# Is this derivation of W in polar form correct?

Tags: complex-analysis

In this derivation of polar form of $ w = u + iv$,

one of the step is,

$\partial w / \partial z = (\partial w / \partial r) * (\partial r / \partial x) + (\partial w / \partial \theta) * (\partial \theta / \partial x) = (\partial w / \partial r) cos \theta - (\partial u / \partial \theta + i \partial v / \partial \theta) * sin \theta /r $

why is it x instead of z,

$\partial w / \partial z = (\partial w / \partial r) * (\partial r / \partial z) + (\partial w / \partial \theta) * (\partial \theta / \partial z)$

And since $x = r cos \theta$, shouldn't

$\partial r / \partial x = 1 / cos \theta$

Comment: Is your question related to the polar version of Cauchy-Riemann equations (written in the right)  ? If such is the case, see [here](https://users.math.msu.edu/users/shapiro/teaching/classes/425/crpolar.pdf) for clarification.

Comment: @JeanMarie That is helpful!

Comment: Another reference [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2971142/305862).